# localStorage значение span удаляется

Tags: javascript, localstorage

У меня есть код

```
<span id="text">Cat</span>
<button onclick="f1()">click</button>

<script>
      function f1(){
      let text = document.getElementById("text");
      var car = "car";
      text.innerHTML = car;
      localStorage.setItem("myText", car);
      }

      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("myText");
      </script>
```

Суть кода - просто менять слово `Cat` на слово которое находится в переменной `car`. Я в этом новичок и не понимаю, почему когда я захожу в панель разработчика в hrome, захожу в раздел `localStorage` а затем удаляю всё, вверху есть `clear all`. После чего все ключи `localStorage` удаляются. После этого я перезагрузил страницу, и слово `Cat` которое изначально было в `span id="text"` пропало. Я просто делаю простенькое приложенице для телефона, которое работает с помощью `localStorage` когда я скачиваю это приложение, открываю, то слова `Cat` которое находилось в `span id="text"` нет, а когда нажимаю на кнопку `onclick="f1()"` То появляется сразу car. Я не мастер по обьяснению, сразу за это извините. В чем проблема и как это решить? буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простейший вариант обработки отсутствующего значения в localStorage, на <s>старом</s>классическом синтаксисе JS - это использование логического ИЛИ в выражении с `getItem`:

```
var text = localStorage.getItem('myText') || 'Cat';
```

Это работает благодаря тому что `getItem` возвращает `null` при отсутствии в хранилище значения с указанным ключом - а логический оператор `||` автоматически преобразует это в `false`, и затем возвращает правый операнд (`'Cat'`, в данном случае).

---

Варианты на **новом** синтаксисе JS, используют деструктуризацию.
Это обусловлено тем, что каждое веб-приложение рано или поздно становится больше, сложнее, и авторы приходят к решению хранить данные структурно (в объекте, а не отдельными значениями). К тому же, сложные приложения часто используют управление состояниями через Redux/Vuex, а там манипуляции структурами гораздо удобнее.

Чтение части значений из объекта в уже существующие переменные (с именами `text`, `bar`, `baz`) в общем виде выглядит так:

```
({
  text    = 'Cat', 
  foo:bar = 42,
  baz     = null
} = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('appData') || '{}'));
```

Несмотря на внешнюю громоздкость, это все же более воспринимаемый синтаксис, чем

```
const appData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('appData') || '{}'); 
text = appData.text || 'Cat'; 
foo = appData.bar || 42;
baz = appData.baz || null;
```

И, это только один из вариантов чтения. Бывает что объект для хранилища читается и лежит в состоянии "как есть", а деструктурируется по надобности (по крайней мере, я так делаю); бывает данные сразу делятся на куски, через `...rest` раскидываясь по нескольким объектам; и т.д..
В общем, пример разбора тут совсем не эталонный, и варьируется: в зависимости от того что хранится, и как приложение с этим работает далее.

Ну а в записи объекта в хранилище, ничего особенного:

```
localStorage.setItem('appData', JSON.stringify({ 
  text, foo: 123, baz, ...someObj 
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (localStorage.getItem("myText")) {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("myText");
}
```